Map property to existing target property with mapperly in c#
I have following code where I want to Map dto into an existing object. I'd expected that the Update method in AddressMapper got called, but the Create gets called.
I can't really find anything useful in the documentation. How should I fix this the correct way?
[Mapper]
[UseStaticMapper(typeof(AddressMapper))]
public static partial class CompanyUpdateMapper
{
    private static partial void Map(CompanyUpdateDTO request, Company company);

    public static Company Map(CompanyUpdateDTO request, IRepository repository)
    {
        Company company = repository.GetById<Company>(request.Id, ["Address"]);
        Map(request, company);
        return company;
    }
}

[Mapper]
public static partial class AddressMapper
{
    private static partial Address MapInternal(AddressDTO address);

    public static Address Create(AddressDTO address)
        => MapInternal(address) ?? new Address();

    [MapperIgnoreTarget(nameof(Address.Id))]
    public static partial void Map(AddressDTO addressDTO, Address address);
}

